# How to allow user to login via Swagger with CSRF TOken?

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, csrf, swagger-ui

[image]

Right now, the login route: `/auth/login` only allows the request to login from other web-portals, but not from Swagger. If I tried to do via Swagger, even with correct credentials I will get this error :

> "message": "invalid csrf token"

[image]

I have to figure away to allow Swagger to log in, but not compromise the existing route.

```
app.post('/auth/login',[csrfProtection], controllers.auth.login);
```

Above, is my login route.

How do I allow my swagger to login to obtain the token? Without compromising my login route with CSRF attack?

**Any suggestions will be a huge help.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this

```
app.post('/auth/login', (req, res, next) => req.get('Origin') === new URL(process.env.PORTAL).origin ? next() : csrfProtection(req, res, next) , controllers.auth.login);
```

This will prevent kept the `csrfProtection` on other origins, and allow only from `Swagger`.